# Bring in or bring into

Tags: prepositions

1. May this day bring happiness in your life.
2. May this day bring happiness into your life.

Which one is correct? Anyone kindly tell me about this.

Comment: 'Into' is more idiomatic, since we speak (in a literal sense) of _bringing_ an object _into_ a place.

Answer (score 3):

Whether to use *in* or *into* with *bring* depends on the presence or absence of a prepositional object.

Consider "He brings in the papers" or "He brings the papers in". There is a direct object (*papers*) but no prepositional object: where he brings them is not specified other than by context.

If you bring the papers into a defined space or area, that destination is a prepositional object and requires *into*: "He brings the papers into the room"; "He brings the papers into London".

The same principle applies with *in/into your life:* here, *your life* is the prepositional object and *into* is needed.

With a sentence like "He brings the papers in London", there is no destination; *in* here means *within*. Someone else would bring papers within Birmingham. While this is similar to your first example sentence, your intended meaning is not the same. You actually want happiness to end up in your life, whereas with my sentences here, the papers are already in London and simply being brought within that area.

[Note that prepositions can vary idiomatically. *Bring into* works as described here; *enter into* (for example) works in a similar way, but not identically and has a different meaning.]

Comment: 'X brings joy/happiness in her life', with the 'within' sense, is not impossible: 'X is a source of happiness in her life'.

Comment: I think *bring* is a stretch there, and it's obviously not what's intended in the question.

Comment: I didn't say I'd recommend it in OP's example. ELU seeks to address complications in English; it's not primarily a Q & A service. Questions are useful – probably essential – vehicles. And 'Whether to use in or into with bring depends on the presence or absence of a prepositional object.' looks like a general statement; it's not given a 'here / in this case' caveat.